# How to Store IDs and Names with a Single ComboBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm populating a drop-down list (ComboBox) with data retrieved via stored procedure.

```
DataTable dtCustomer = da.ExecuteProcedureWithRS("pCustomerList_s", p, parms); //get data
foreach (DataRow dr in dtCustomer.Rows) //loop through DataTable rows
{
    CustomerNameBox.Items.Add(dr[1]); //add customer name to combobox
}
```

This is fairly easy. However, at position 0 in each row is the ID of the customer, of which I also want to keep track, and associate with the name in CustomerNameBox.

A colleague mentioned I can make another dropdown, hide it, and do the following:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtCustomer.Rows) //loop through DataTable rows
{
    CustomerIDBox.Items.Add(dr[0]); //add customer ID to combobox
    CustomerNameBox.Items.Add(dr[1]); //add customer name to combobox    
}
```

Then I can match names to IDs 1:1 by grabbing a name from the NameBox and its ID from the IDBox - e.g. `var id = CustomerIDBox.Items[16]; var name = CustomerNameBox.Items[16]`

This seems like a kludge to me. I'm aware I can use a `Dictionary<string, int>` or similar to store key-value pairs, but **is there some way to store the ID and name natively with a single ComboBox?**

Comment: [smh] Please, dont listen to that colleague of yours anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

Where
"Key" and "Value"  are column name in your datatable

```
this.comboBox1.DataSource = yourdatatable;
this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key";
this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

OR with Loop

```
for(int i=0; i<dtCustomer.Rows.Count();i++)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(dtCustomer.Rows[i][0], dtCustomer.Rows[i][1]))
}
```

Comment: I feel much better about this, thanks. And the single-line binding is a big improvement too.